# OnItemDataBound doesn't show full list of items bound

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater that has an `OnItemDataBound` event on it. For some reason the repeater has three items being bound to it. But then I try the below it only writes '2' at the top of the page. The repeater itself does show the three items but this loop in the `OnDataBound` event doesn't see the last item. Why?

```
protected void colourRepeater_ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptAssoicatedProducts.Items)
    {
        count++;
    }
    Response.Write(count.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
int count = 0;
protected void colourRepeater_ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    Response.Write("Items so far : " + count.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT:**
When the `ItemDataBound` event is triggered, the `RepeaterItem` is not linked to the `Repeater` yet ... only the related data is.

Comment: yes that does work but im then wanting to access controls in the item i.e  Literal litSomeStuff = ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litSomeStuff "));

Comment: never mind worked it out! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.onitemdatabound.aspx